# Log4j 2 performance: is single-threaded Console logging faster in Logback than Log4j 2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback, log4j2

Recently, I have experimented with Log4j 2 logging and tried to compare its performance with Logback on my local Mac machine. Surprisingly, I see Logback performs better in my test cases. I expected Log4j 2 to do better than Logback as claimed by the Log4j 2 website, so I want to check if I am doing something wrong in using Log4j 2.

For testing, I have used direct Log4j 2 and Logback **without** using SLF4J. Also, the **`ConsoleAppender`** was used for both logging frameworks, and the pattern I tested is:

```
<Pattern>%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
```

The logging test code is:

```
logger.info("This is a bootstrap message");

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
    logger.info("Order={} successfully processed", "ABC123");
}
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
logger.info("time taken to process={} ms", end - start);
```

I ran the test 10 times for each logging separately and tried to take the average time taken to process. Unexpectedly, logback performed better in each run. I have tried disabling the default GC logging that comes with Log4j 2 using the params:

```
-Dlog4j2.enable.threadlocals=false -Dlog4j2.enable.direct.encoders=false
```

but I still didn't see any improvement over logback. Could anyone confirm whether I am doing is correct or not?

*log4j 2 config:*

```
<Configuration status="INFO" debug="false">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.mycompany.app" level="INFO"/>
    <Root level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

*Logback config:*

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="1 hour">

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:S} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.mycompany.app" level="info"/>

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: In any case you can do `Task.Run(() => logger.info("Order={} successfully processed", "ABC123"));` which will run it in another thread so you won't get blocked. Only problem that might occur is fire-and-forget mentality that is if it fails you're not gonna know it.

Comment: Hi Stan, thanks, but this doesnt make any difference to their performance and both frameworks will be benefited by this , I am trying to see if i did something wrong in configuring log4j 2 from my end

Comment: Please also show your Log4j2 configuration and Logback configuration so people can reproduce your test.

Comment: Hi @RemkoPopma configs added

Answer (score 8):

I think it's great that you're trying to independently verify that Log4j2's performance is really as good as advertised.

I ran your test and these are my results. As you can see, your test gives a slightly better score for Log4j 2 than Logback on my laptop.

```
Log4j 2.6.1    Logback 1.1.7
-----------    -------------
  7,337 ms       7,413 ms     
  6,956 ms       7,097 ms     
  6,748 ms       7,827 ms     
  6,828 ms       7,480 ms     
  6,745 ms       7,067 ms     
  7,146 ms       7,003 ms     
  6,852 ms       7,036 ms
```

So, what does these result mean? Your test shows that the **synchronous** logging throughput of the **Console** appender from a **single** thread is slightly better in Log4j 2 than in Logback.

To get a more complete picture of performance of the logging libraries you also want to compare **asynchronous** logging, different appenders (especially the **File** appender) and logging from **multiple** threads.

- [Asynchronous logging](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#Performance) is *much* faster than synchronous logging, and applications that care about performance will usually log asynchronously. I consider async logging performance to be the most important benchmark when comparing logging libraries performance.
- Console logging is at least [50x slower](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html#whichAppender) (!) than logging to a File. It will slow down your application and should be **very carefully** used (and preferably avoided) in a production configuration. So measuring Console logging performance is not very useful. Most applications log to a File so the File appender may be a better place to start a performance investigation.
- Many applications are multithreaded. Lock contention can slow down your application if the logging library is not carefully designed to deal with this. If you measure logging from multiple threads you'll find that Log4j 2's fine-grained locking gives [*much* higher throughput than Logback](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html#fileLoggingComparison). (With asynchronous logging the [difference is even more pronounced](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#Asynchronous_Throughput_Comparison_with_Other_Logging_Packages).)

Measuring multithreaded logging needs extra care because you don't want to measure until all threads have started, so you'll need a [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) or something similar.

In general I recommend looking at [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) for a very solid and easy to use benchmarking tool. The [Log4j 2 performance page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html) points to the JMH benchmarks used to produce the results on the page. (For example, [FileAppenderBenchmark](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-perf/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/perf/jmh/FileAppenderBenchmark.java).) These may be a good starting point to get familiar with JMH and performance testing in general.

Good luck, and stay curious!

Comment: Hi, @Remko , Thanks for your time in running my code samples.  I will take a look JMH and try to compare the results. I will post the results here soon.

Comment: How do I clone the Log4j2 repo to my desktop and run the tests locally ?

Comment: Cloning and building: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/build.html Most JMH benchmarks have javadoc on how to run them.

Comment: @RemkoPopma does this performance impact on console logging as well hold true for running within Docker containers? I don't know what is causing this negative impact, but I would assume that it will be about the same for a docker scenario, is this right?

Comment: I would assume that console logging is slower than file logging in Docker also, but I don't have any personal experience with Docker.

Comment: My +1 is for the information that console logging is 50x slower than file

Answer (score 2):

When creating tests like this you really should be using JMH. I would suggest that you look at the tests in the log4j-perf module for examples on how to do this.

Also, you are only testing a single thread. Many of the issues with logback only show up in multi-threaded cases. You can see this in some of the graphs at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html. Note that all the data in those graphs came from tests in the log4j-perf module that you can run yourself.

Also, unless you are going to actually log to the console I wouldn't use that in a test since it is the slowest place to log, although the next release of log4j will have some improvements to that.

Finally, if you have questions about our tests please feel free to ask on one of the log4j mailing lists. Remko has been working with some experts in performance testing and can provide you with good pointers on how to create good meaningful tests.

Comment: Hi @rgoers, Thanks for your reply